# SQL injection when client is only selecting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security, sql-injection

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), SQL injection is something one would have to prevent. In an application where the user is only selecting from the database, how would this be a concern?

Comment: Yes, yes is is.

Comment: Yes. It is a concern.

Comment: @JohnConde How? The MySQL user that I am using only has SELECT access and the code itself is only running a SELECT function.

Comment: If you can SELECT you can still get sensitive data from the database.

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier I am only concerned about them editing the database; there is no sensitive information on it that I am aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some examples of problems that SQL injection could allow even if the user is restricted to SELECT privilege:

- The attacker could read data intended to be read only by other users. Many applications use the same MySQL user to connect, and then enforce further data-access restrictions with application code. I.e. I'm only supposed to see the shopping cart that I created. But with SQL injection, I could read everyone's shopping cart, their purchase history, their credit card number, and so on.
- The attacker could read the hashed passwords of other accounts, crack them (on his own computer), and then log in to another user with greater privileges.
- The attacker could run a [denial-of-service attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) by running a SELECT query that uses too many resources. For example, on MySQL, the table `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_SETS` is readable even for a user with *no* privileges. Now what is going to happen when the attacker runs this query:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM CHARACTER_SETS, CHARACTER_SETS, CHARACTER_SETS,
  CHARACTER_SETS, CHARACTER_SETS, CHARACTER_SETS) AS t ORDER BY 1
  ```

  It tries to create a temp table on disk for 2,839,760,855,281 rows. I predict that will exhaust disk space on your server.

Your question sounds like you're fishing for a rationale for skipping writing safe code that protects against SQL injection.

Sorry, no dice. You need to write safe code.

Answer (score 0):

Any thing the user does that will lead to CRUD operation on the Data Source should be treated as dangerous and all precaution taken to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Why? The MySQL user that I am using only has SELECT access and the code itself is only running a SELECT function.

Comment: Because, how about the SQL injection tricking your so-called user to select all data and send it to the caller?